# warning in pycharm, with sort(key = len) function

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings

While I've seemingly written a pretty easy code(just 3 lines), my Pycharm issues a warning which  I just don't understand. The code runs, but i'd like to understand the warning. Thanks in advance!

```
str1 = ['hello', 'there', 'graham', 'pushkin', 'fizzybubblech', 'ciao', 'meestersonuvabeech', 'russia'] # wrote this just to amuse myself

str1.sort(key = len) # within the parenthesis is where the warning is issued 

print(str1)

> #This is the warning i recieve. First questionn in overflow, so i just pasted the whole thing 
>Expected type 'Optional[(str) -> Any]' (matched
> generic type 'Optional[(_T) -> Any]'), got '(o: Sized) -> int' instead
> less... (Ctrl+F1)  Inspection info: This inspection detects type
> errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck
> typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases.
> Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in
> Python 3 function annotations.
```

Comment: it's just because `len` returns an int and not a string. looks like a bug in type hinting but it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: I made a bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is caused by the fact that pycharm mistakenly believes that the len function cannot have a str as an input -- as said by [Alex Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2482744/alex-hall). This is not an error on your part and you will simply have to wait until pycharm fixes the bug.

If you really don't want to see that pesky error message, you could replace
`key = len` with `key=lambda x: len(x)` which simply removes Pycharm's ability to see the return type. But I advise against doing so since it does not make your code clearer and does slow your code down.

Furthermore, you could remove the spaces around the = and add another space before the # to make your code [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant. That would turn the line into `str1.sort(key=len)  # within the parenthesis is where the warning is issued`. This will prevent any warnings from popping up in the future if you ever turn PEP8 checking on.

Comment: `Expected type 'Optional[(str) -> Any]'` doesn't indicate that it expects the key to return a string, but rather to accept one.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the clarification!